# How can I display image metadata?

Tags: filters, attachments, the-content, post-meta

I'm trying to add a filter to `the_content` that will find all images in the post and append the custom attachment metadata `credit` to it.

Here's the functions I've have:

**Adds the Credit field to attachment details page:** *(this works)*

```
function attachment_field_credit( $field, $post ) {
    $field[ 'credit' ] = array(
        'label' => 'Credit',
        'input' => 'text',
        'value' => get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'credit', true ),
    );
    return $field;
}
```

**Saves the Credit field:** *(this works)*

```
function attachment_field_credit_save( $post, $attachment ) {
    if( isset( $attachment[ 'credit' ] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post[ 'ID' ], 'credit', $attachment[ 'credit' ] );
    return $post;
}
```

**Search the content for all available images:** *(this works)*

```
function find_images( $content ) {
    return preg_replace_callback( '/(<\s*img[^>]+)(src\s*=\s*"[^"]+")([^>]+>)/i', array( $this, 'attach_image_credit' ), $content );
}
```

**Appends credit metadata to each image:** *(this doesn't work)*

```
function attach_image_credit( $images ) {
    global $post;
    $credit = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'credit', true );
    $replacement = $images[0] . $credit;
    return $replacement;
}
```

If I replace `$credit` value with `<span>Hello World!</span>` the text will be displayed on the page as intended. There must be something wrong with the way I'm trying to `get_the_meta` value for `credit`.

---

**UPDATE**

If I manually replace:

```
get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'credit', true );
```

with:

```
get_post_meta( 446, 'credit', true );
```

It works! So all I need to do is to figure out a way to get the attachment ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the credit data is saved in the *attachment's* post meta, not the main post:

```
$credit = get_post_meta( $post->ID /* Wrong ID! */, 'credit', true );
```

Instead you need to catch the ID of the inserted image:

```
function attach_image_credit( $images ) {
    $return = $images[0];

    // Get the image ID from the unique class added by insert to editor: "wp-image-ID"
    if ( preg_match( '/wp-image-([0-9]+)/', $return, $match ) ) {
        if ( $credit = get_post_meta( $match[1] /* Captured image ID */, 'credit', true ) )
            $return .= $credit;
    }

    return $return;
}
```